# Passing the environment variables to the launched process bash script

Tags: c++, linux, bash, shell

Under linux, I have a bash script, that launches a c++ program binary. 
What I need to do is set an environment variable in that script, and access that variable
inside the launched C++ program using `getenv` .

Here is the code for the script

```
#!/bin/bash
export SAMPLE_VAR=1
./c++_binary
```

The c++ program:

```
char * env_var = getenv("SAMPLE_VAR");
if (env_var != NULL) printf("var set\n");
```

However this does not seem to work. From what I understand is that when we execute the script, it will run in a new subshell and set the environment variable SAMPLE_BAR there, but the C++ binary is launched in the same subshell as well (may be I am wrong here) so it should have access to the SAMPLE_VAR.  I even tried writing a separate script that just sets the env variable, and in the main script I called that script as `source env_var_set.sh`  to no avail.

Is it possible to pass on a newly set environment variable to a program this way ?
Thanks

Comment: Did you mean `char * env_var = getenv("SAMPLE_VAR")`? Extra quotes can make all the difference.

Comment: Have you tried `int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp);` also?  The `envp` should capture environment varibales as well.

Comment: @mvp, yes sorry, I did put in the quotes, edited the quest.

Comment: this is weird - you are doing it correctly, and it should just work. About the only reason why it would not if you have some security software at work, something like [AppArmor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835664/how-does-apparmor-do-environment-scrubbing).

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", is `getenv` returning `NULL`?

Comment: Yes it returns NULL, i did a system("printenv")  inside the program as well. And the SAMPE_VAR isnt set in the environment of the program.

Comment: Your question mentions SAMPLE_VAR and SAMPLE_BAR; your last comment mentions SAMPE_VAR.  You have to get your spelling consistent.  Your code should work fine.  Your script could use: `SAMPLE_VAR=1 ./c++_binary` too, which exports the variable only to the one program.

Comment: Ah Sorry for the Typos, And my mistake, Inside the script I was launching the binary with 'sudo' which ran it in root's env and didnt have the variable set there. Removed sudo and it worked fine. Sorry for the confusion. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution here.*

Ah Sorry for the Typos, And my mistake, Inside the script I was launching the binary with 'sudo' which ran it in root's env and didnt have the variable set there. Removed sudo and it worked fine. Sorry for the confusion. Cheers. – Abdullah

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need to `source` your shell script in order for the `env` variable to be set. and secondly include quotes in the `getenv` call.

```
char * env_var = getenv("SAMPLE_VAR");
if (env_var != NULL) printf("var set\n");
```

Comment: He's exporting the variable and starting the binary from the same script. Sourcing versus executing the script won't make any difference.